# IP-over-USB for Linux?

Tags: linux, usb

I would like to transfer large files between two computers. The machines do not have 10G ethernet ports but do have USB 3.2 gen 2 ports.

Does Linux have any solutions for doing point-to-point IP over USB at 10Gbps?

Comment: It is very unclear why your connection speed needs to be 10Gbps

Comment: @Luuk "I would like to transfer large files". Perhaps I should have also mentioned that I would like to not wait days and weeks? What difference does this make?

Comment: The fastest way would be to use an USB3.0 external (SSD)hard drive, which should do about 4.8 Gbits/sec.   But then you need to copy to the hard drive, switch it to the other computer, and copy it again. so effectively you will reach less than half that, when looking at total time needed.

Comment: The linked answer is 10 years old, meaning that the data transfer rates are 2 generations old. Today there are USB3 PC-PC "transfer cables", and USB3-Ethernet adapters. effective speed of these devices are carefully muted. I think the question needs to be re-opened.

Comment: I think the best way today to move large amount of data using USB3.2x1 Gen2 ports is to use external SSD, but not the kind suggested by @Luuk , but using a modern USB3.2x1 Gen2 enclosure with NVMe 4xGen4 m.2 storage stick (Samsung 980 1-2TB capacity, not smaller, or similar). These enclosures would provide up to 1GByte/s transfer rate on large files (100GB). A bunch of smaller files will drag the performance way down, as usual.